# Multiple versions of a website each with its own root directory using Apache

Tags: apache, web, directory, root

I have multiple versions of my website. Each resides in its own folder, for example:

```
site_v1/  
  index.html  
  page1.html    

site_v2/  
  index.html  
  page1.html
```

How can I configure apache so that each version of the site has its own definition of the root directory?

In other words, I want site_v1/index.html to think the root directory is site_v1, and site_v2/index.html to think the root directory is site_v2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `VirtualHost` directive.

[Apache manual on virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/)

Answer (score 2):

As @Pekka wrote, you are indeed looking for the `VirtualHost` directive, but I though I might add an example configuration for your virtual host configuration. This should be placed in your `httpd.conf` file, edited to your preference, and remember to fill in the full path:

```
NameVirtualHost v1.yoursite.com:80
<VirtualHost v1.yoursite.com:80>
    ServerName v1.yoursite.com
    ServerAlias v1.yoursite.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/site_v1
    ErrorLog /path/to/prefered/error.log
    CustomLog /path/to/prefered/access.log combined
    <Directory /path/to/site_v1>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost v2.yoursite.com:80
<VirtualHost v2.yoursite.com:80>
    ServerName v2.yoursite.com
    ServerAlias v2.yoursite.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/site_v2
    ErrorLog /path/to/prefered/error.log
    CustomLog /path/to/prefered/access.log combined
    <Directory /path/to/site_v2>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you want, you may chose to use a different access/error log for each version of your site. Just change the name/path to the log file, and you're done. `/path/to` are the path to the site folder, and v1.yoursite.com & v2.yoursite.com should be changed to the relative domains you want to use for each version. If you don't want to change the log files, remove the `ErrorLog` and `CustomLog` directives and I'll default to the main log files set in httpd.conf